# Unable to install pyopenssl in MacOs for python2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run scrapy command with this in python2.7 in Mac OS:

```
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl pornHubSpider".split())
```

But i'm receiving this error:

```
from OpenSSL._util import lib as pyOpenSSLlib
ImportError: No module named _util
```

When I try to install

```
sudo pip install pyopenssl --user --upgrade
```

I get:

```
build/temp.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/_openssl.c:493:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
    #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-v_oSaa/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-A590v3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-v_oSaa/cryptography
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are either missing or using an old version of **openssl** or **pip**.

1. In your terminal, do `openssl version`. If it is installed, do `brew upgrade openssl`. If not installed, do  `brew install openssl`
2. Update pip - `pip install -U upgrade` if you are not using the latest version.
3. Install *pyopenssl* using `pip install pyopenssl`. If properly installed, skip step 4.
4. Install *pyopenssl* package using
   `pip install pyopenssl --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"`

Reference: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3489